# How to remove "add document" button of document library programmatically using C#?

Tags: development, document-library, office-365, document, sandbox-solution

**I have created a document library programmatically using C#.** Now, I want that when any particular document library created then its **'add document' button should not view** or if possible then whole panel of add/edit/delete should be invisible.
I am working on Office365 & sandbox solution.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could hide a `New` button in List View using:

**CSS**

```
button.js-listview-qcbNewButton {
  display:none;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('button.js-listview-qcbNewButton').hide();
```

How to apply the changes:

- Switch the page (`AllItems.aspx`) into edit mode
- Add `Script Editor` or `Content Editor` web part into page.
- For JavaScript code, put the specified code by wrapping it using
  `script` tag, for example: `<script
  type="text/javascript">$('button.js-listview-qcbNewButton').hide();</script>`
- Save the page

Answer (score 0):

**whole panel of add/edit/delete should be invisible**
You have to create new form and add this CSS into its PlaceHolderMain section

```
$('.ms-dlgFrame').load(function () {
  $('.s4-pr.s4-ribbonrowhidetitle', frames[1].document).hide();
});
```

For more info refer to

http://geekswithblogs.net/venkatx5/archive/2010/11/17/how-to-hide-top-bar-ribbon-quick-launch-in-sharepoint.aspx

http://phinotworking.com/hiding-the-ribbon-when-using-sp-ui-modaldialog-showmodaldialog/